# Generating a footnote from selected text

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am trying to script InDesign using ExtendScript. I want the script to cut the selected text, insert a footnote and paste the text into the footnote body. What I have tried:

```
 function makeFootnoteOfSelection(){
   var fnText = app.activeDocument.selection[0];
         // this should actually clone the selected text, not reference it, because the next statement zaps it from memory
   app.activeDocument.selection[0].remove();  // works
   var fNote = app.activeDocument.selection[0].footnotes.add();  // works, adds an empty footnote with a reference
   fNote.contents = fnText.contents;
         // this replaces the reference number, I was hoping to retain it and just add the text
         // fNote.contents += fnText.contents; also replaces the reference number
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**InDesign CS5:**

```
function makeFootnoteOfSelection(){

  // Reference the selection
  var fnText = app.activeDocument.selection[0];

  // Add an empty footnote where the selected text is
  var fNote = app.activeDocument.selection[0].footnotes.add();

  // Move the selected text at the end of the empty footnote
  fnText.move(LocationOptions.AFTER, fNote.insertionPoints[-1]);
}
```

**InDesign CS4:**

```
function makeFootnoteOfSelection(){

  // Reference the selection
  var fnText = app.activeDocument.selection[0];

  //  Position of the text end
  var endPoint = fnText.length - 1;

  // Add an empty footnote where the selected text is
  var fNote = app.activeDocument.selection[0].footnotes.add();

  // Duplicate the selected text at the end of the empty footnote
  fnText.duplicate(LocationOptions.AFTER, fNote.insertionPoints[-1]);

  // Delete the old Text
  fnText.characters.itemByRange(0, endPoint).contents = "";
}
```

Comment: The script errors out with "Text cannot be moved to its current location" at the third step. I think it is because the footnote is included in the selection after step 2.

Comment: Are you using InDesign CS4? It gave me the same error. But I found a different solution that worked for me. Your guess may be right. Footnotes are tied to a specific insertionPoint, I imagine. Therefore, if this point lies within the selection, the footnote does too. But it seems they changed the behaviour in CS5 to be more like what you would expect.

Comment: Excellent! You're a genius. How did you learn all this? From the object model viewer? By studying sample scripts? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot \*blush\*. There is a nicer version of the object model viewer on http://www.jongware.com/idjshelp.html , which I use extensively. Sometimes it's just trial and error to find out how things (like footnotes) are handled by InDesign. I almost never use Adobes code samples because I don't like their programming style.

Comment: Great link. I really like jongware's reference.